How to reload page with hashtag (javascript)
I want to check if url contains hashtag with javascript. If yes do nothing if not refresh with default hash. So I did...
HTML:
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="utabs">
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab1" onClick="window.location.hash='tab1';" data-toggle="tab"data-url="tab1.php?cal=<?=$cal?>">Tab1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2" onClick="window.location.hash='tab2';" data-toggle="tab" data-url="tab2.php?cal=<?=$cal?>">Tab2</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab3" onClick="window.location.hash='tab3';" data-toggle="tab" data-url="tab3.php?cal=<?=$cal?>">Tab3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab1"><?include "SL/tab1.php"?></div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2"></div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab3"></div>
  </div><!-- tab-content -->

Javascript:
    var url = window.location.href;
        if (url.indexOf("#") > 0){
            var activeTab = url.substring(url.indexOf("#") + 1);
            $('.nav[role="tablist"] a[href="#'+activeTab+'"]').tab('show');
        }
    //tabs
        //ajax tab
        $('#utabs a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
            var href = this.hash;
            var pane = $(this);

            // ajax load from data-url
            $(href).load(url,function(result){
                pane.tab('show');
            });
        });
    var hash = window.location.hash;
        // load first tab content
        if (hash) {//if hash detected then reload the content
            console.log(hash+` detected`);
            $(hash).load($('.active a').attr("data-url"),function(result){
              $('.active a').tab('show');//Current tab not load here!
            });
        } else {//if no hash then load with default tab
          console.log(`no hash!!`)
            window.location.href +='#tab1';
            location.reload();                
        }                   

But there're 2 problems:

Page keep reloading because it detects the hash in url
The content is not load into the tab according to the hash.


What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? That's so little code that even debugging with alerts or console.log could help if you don't want to use a proper debugger
